# Ubuntu 17.04 forgetting wifi password after every reboot

Tags: wireless, network-manager, connection, 17.04

So, Ubuntu forgets my wifi password and connection every time network-manager restarts, so I have to type in password every time it boots. Changing connection from shared to singe user didn't help. "Connect automatically" check box is checked in nework manager.

I'm using Ubuntu Budgie.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the network icon in the top panel. In "Edit Connections..." delete the profile for that particular wireless network, and any duplicates like profilename1/profilename2, and then connect to that same wireless network. It'll ask for your password as it recreates the profile, but it shouldn't ask again.

Comment: Hello, there is no wifi icon in top right corner.

Comment: Oh, I now see that you're using Budgie. I'm not familiar with that. Where/how do you select which wireless network to connect to? That's where you can find the network icon. Is there a place there for editing your network connections?

Comment: ps: it's probably the icon with the two arrows on it...

Comment: Deleting it didn't work.

Comment: And you're sure you deleted any duplicates?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  After rebooting I have to reconnect manually.